# how can I solve makefile error in omnet++

Tags: c++, veins

I created my own code in veins in traci file and built it. I have makefile error how can I solve in?

```
2 errors generated.
Makefile:177: recipe for target '../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.o' failed
make[1]: *** [../out/gcc-debug/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/sepideh/src/omnetpp-5.0/samples/veins/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed
16:41:24 Build Finished (took 1m:9s.529ms)
```

Comment: Can you post the Makefile or at least the bit around line 51?

Comment: Thanks that you replied me. first of all I created my own file in veins but I encountered with makefile errors when I build it .I think my makefile errors were made by my programming or my file was not registered in veins.

Comment: excuse me I posted my new makefile error

Comment: This error is useless without the output just above it and any custom (makefile) code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. The solution for me was to configurate omnet++ without certain packages.

```
 ./configure WITH_OSGEARTH=no WITH_OSG=no WITH_QTENV=no
```

and then make like this:

```
make -j3
```